# Shiny R: Query in global.R or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny application that connects to a database with several tables with each one having several thousand rows, and in a very few cases a few hundreds of thousand rows (not more than 500,000 rows). The plan is to create an application that will graphically present either via charts (using `ggplot2` and `googleVis`) or via tables.

As certain piece of data will be used several times in various charts or tables my question is the following: Would it be more efficient (from an application's performance perspective) to query some of the most frequently used datasets when the application starts (in **global.R**) or query the database every time I want to **make a plot**?

Here are a few cases that describe more specifically the above question:

- Case1

  - Query table ABC once in global R and create dataframe "df"
  - Create a reactive dataset using ABC: "dataformychart".
  - Plot output$mychartusing dataformychart()
- Case 1b

  - query table ABC once in global R and create dataframe "df"
  - plot output$mychart using only required data by slicing "df" within output$mychart
- Case 2

  - create a reactive dataset named "dataformychart" and within this query the database
  - plot output$mychart using dataformychart()

Comment: If it's a large set of data then you should only query it once and create an object in your `global.R` file. Subsetting / slicing it to meet the needs of your different plots will be a lot faster than repeatedly querying a database. I'm sure you could easily test each of your three cases so there's really no need to sit around wondering about it.

Comment: You can also do the query in `server.r` but before the `shinyServer()` function. This will only query it once and it will be avialable across all sessions.

Comment: @nrussell I appreciate your comment/answer. The reason that I believe I couldn't easily test is that if you just have a few charts then performance wise it wouldn't make a big difference. Just trying to be proactive.